# How can i edit the product template of Magento Website

Tags: magento, ftp

Sorry for asking for very basic question. Actually i am very new to magento hence couldn't find the solution..Here is the question:

I have a magento ecommerce website and i want to edit the product template of the website.
I have both magento and FTP credentials. But not able to figure out where is the actual product template.

in which folder i have to look for the product template file?

I want to append some HTML to each product page hence i am looking for it.
Please Advise.

Hope to get some help.

Regards,
Rich

Comment: go to app/design/frontend/{themename}/default/template/catalog/product/

Comment: Magento templates are Lego blocks that have holes that are filled by other Lego blocks. They start with the page and work their way down in a hierarchy. They also break up into logical sections. Depending on what you want to change in your Product View page, you may end up editing one or more html blocks. As Tamil points out, look in template/catalog/product for product related, template/catalog/category for category related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to debug this type of issue when new to magento is to "Turn on Template Path Hints"

1. Log into the admin
2. Goto -> System ->Configuration, and on the bottom of the list select “Developer”
3. click on Debug – you will only see “Profiler”. Here is the trick – you have to switch the “Current Configuration Scope:” [in the upper left] to a website instead of default. Select “Main Website”.
4. Now you will see the selection for Template Path Hints – check yes. This will display the path of the template for each block of the page so you can find stuff! You can also choose to “Add Block Names to Hints” to see the corresponding model class for the block.

Which going to point you to  app/design/frontend/[theme]/default/template/catalog/product/*

Read more @ http://www.redlightblinking.com/blog/magento-debugging-how-to-debug-template-paths-logging-and-display-errors

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the previous answer make sure to disable the cache otherwise you might not see the results right away.

The Product page has many files attached but mainly the most importants, in my opinion, areI

the media.phtml that controls the size of your mage, more views, etc then you have the
the upsell.phtml that call the upsell products and 
the view.phtml that combine all these files.

You can find them at

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view

Copy these files and paste them in your theme directory. DO NOT OVERRIDE THEM! and also keep in mind you have: single product, configurable product, etc so you'll have to edit those files as well if you need!

Hope this helps and any feedback from other users is always appreciated.

Comment: It helped me a lot Mike, sorry for a delayed response!

Answer (score 0):

I have a Magento e-commerce website and I want to edit the product template of the website. I have both Magento and FTP credentials. But not able to figure out where is the actual product template. in which folder do I have to look for the product template file, I would like to edit my product by adding some code. I found this folder in FTP /public_html/app/design/frontend/ET/base/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/productlabels.phtml

**I edit some code**

unit price :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var Quantity = document.getElementById("qty").value;
    var UnitPrice = document.getElementById("options[4]").value;
    var vUnitPrice = vUnitPrice / vQuantity;
    vUnitPrice = $("#vUnitPrice ").val(total2.toFixed(2));
    document.write(vUnitPrice);
  }
</script>
```

but nothing changes, help me please